# Html.ValidationMessage: bug or feature?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I try to use the @Html.ValidationMessage() helper.

If I only provide the modelName it only shows up if there is an error.

If I provide an explicit validationMessage it will show up no matter what (even if the field is valid):

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("elem_" + i, "This will show up no matter what!")
```

This is contrary to the description.

From the System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageHelper function (I ILSpied it):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
{
    tagBuilder.SetInnerText(validationMessage);
}
else
{
    if (modelError != null)
    {
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(ValidationExtensions.GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, modelState));
    }
}
```

As you can see if you provide a validationMessage it will show up.

Is this a bug or is it intended.
And how can I circumvent this?

Comment: It looks to me that when you explicitly supply the validation message it shows at runtime, however if you don't, this is the attribute that is populated at execution time after a model validation error, which will look for this property and supply the validation message.

Comment: FYI there is no need to ILSpy the source code. The MVC3 source code has been available via an open source license for a while now. You can download it and view the entire WebRuntime source without a decompilation tool.

Comment: ianaldo21 yes. danludwig yes, but ILSpy is also very convinient with its search and navigation functionality.